Message from each loop iteration during quarto render
I am using a loop in R in a quarto document
When I render the quarto document via Rstudio, I would like to see in the background jobs how far in the loop the process is.
When I work interactively, this works:
species <- iris$Species |> unique()

for(i in species) {
  message(i)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

However, when rendering, no message appears in the Background Jobs pane. I have tried with print() and cat() as well.
Is there a workaround to this?

Seems it's related: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7443. Far awarie from PC at the moment to check it, but you might try.

The solution is to add #| message: !expr NA in the quarto code block.
Read more here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/7443
#| message: !expr NA
species <- iris$Species |> unique()

for(i in species) {
  message(i)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

